# TortoiseSVN diff on directory only shows propinfo - what gives?

Tags: tortoisesvn

I just merged a directory and am doing a TortoiseSVN diff to check for changes before committing. I can see from the file explorer that I have modified several files, but I can't see anything from the diff, only the propinfo. It seems I modified `svn:mergeinfo` while merging, and that is all the diff is showing me.

How do I see the actual files that have changed??? Using Kdiff3 vs TortoiseMerge doesn't make a difference.

TortoiseSVN version 1.9.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When propinfo is modified, TortoiseSVN apparently only shows this propinfo when diffing a directory, *if* you use "SVN diff" from the context menu.

You can work around this by using **Check for Updates** from the context menu rather than **SVN diff**.

This works because "Check for Updates" appears (?) to be equivalent to the command `TortoiseProc.exe /command:diff /path:. /ignoreprops`, while "SVN diff" does not pass the `ignoreprops` flag.